# Python multiprocessing.Manager Namespace - slow performance?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python multiprocessing to split a task into multiple processes. My CPU has 4 physical and 8 virtual cores. I hoped for 100% utilization on all cores but when using a pool of 4 child processes I observe 100% on 1 core and 9% on 3. Since I am using a `multiprocessing.Manager Namespace` I wonder if that is the culprit. The child processes are only reading from the shared namespace (not writing). Perhaps the shared Namespace does not allow concurrent read access - do I need to specify somehow that no locking should be done?

In my actual code, the shared Namespace is large, comprising large lists and numpy arrays, so another cause might be the time it takes to create it. Is the shared Namespace created just once, or is it created each time a new child process is created (assuming no changes in the data within the Namespace)?

Example code:

```
import multiprocessing
import worker
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
multiProcShared = mgr.Namespace()
multiProcShared.a = 25
multiProcShared.b = 40
multiProcShared.c = 10
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
allResults = []
max = xrange(100)
for segmentNum in max:
    allResults.append(pool.apply_async(worker.worker, args=(multiProcShared, segmentNum)))
```

UPDATE: I suspect that since I am passing large data to the child processes there may be significant overhead in the data handover. I think the data is pickled and then unpickled?. If so then does python multiprocessing performance degrade with the size of data passed to the child process? Does this change based on whether the data is passed via a shared namespace vs. via function arguments?

Comment: I am currently dealing with this same blocker. Any chance you discovered any workarounds?

Comment: No. I gave up on Python multiprocessing.